# Populating the value IN a json object with the value from another json object

Tags: javascript, json

I'm performing an ajax call and returning a json formatted data.

```
var ColorName = json.features[r].attributes.ColorName;
```

Chrome shows the value as "0,255,0,204" which corresponds to R,G,B,A (A is transparency)
http://cl.ly/image/362k1K083o3c/ColorName%20value.jpg

What I'd like to do is take `ColorName` and pass it into the object below:

```
var symbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol({
  "color": [ColorName],
  "size": 12,
  "angle": -30,
  "xoffset": 0,
  "yoffset": 0,
  "type": "esriSMS",
  "style": "esriSMSCircle",
  "outline": {
    "color": [0,0,0,255],
    "width": 1,
    "type": "esriSLS",
    "style": "esriSLSSolid"
  }
});
```

If I hard code the values into the object, it works but not when I pass it in as I've shown above.  I'm assuming it is a syntax issue as everything else is working and i'm not getting any errors.

============ updated =================

Here is a snippet of the json formatted data as seen in FireFox

```
        {
      "recordsReturned":"213",
      "status":"pass",
      "msg":"213 record(s) found",  
      "geometryType" : "esriGeometryPoint",
      "spatialReference" : {
        "wkid" : 4326
      },
      "features" : [

        {
          "attributes" : {
            "name" : "XYZ Medical Center",
            "statusID" : "1",
            "NamedColor":"0,255,0,204"
          },
          "geometry" : {
            "x" : -77.4954450,
            "y" : 38.2170020
          }
        }, 
        {
          "attributes" : {
            "name" : "ABC Medical Center",
            "statusID" : "1",
            "NamedColor":"0,255,0,204"
          },
          "geometry" : {
            "x" : -76.3069444444,
            "y" : 36.8447222222
          }
        },
```

And here is a snippet of looping over the returned json object:

```
        if (json.status == 'pass'){
        for ( var r = 0; r < json.recordsReturned;r=r+1){
                var ColorName = json.features[r].attributes.NamedColor;
                ...
```

I hope this helps...

Comment: Show us how you are trying to achieve this. "Everything else is working and no errors" is not helpful because it refers to code we can't see.

Comment: Are you sure the value is already set? You're talking of ajax calls, are you sure you're setting the value in the ajax callback?

Comment: Yes, when I enable debugger, I can add a break point and then verify the values are showing up.  What I'm kind of unsure of (see image link) is if the value being displayed inside of the double quotes includes the double quotes or are the double quotes just identifying the start and end of the data value.

Answer (score 0):

Very subtle difference but when I changed it up like this:

```
    var symbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol({
        **"color": ColorName,**
        "size": 12,
        "angle": -30,
        "xoffset": 0,
        "yoffset": 0,
        "type": "esriSMS",
        "style": "esriSMSCircle",
        "outline": {
        "color": [0,0,0,255],
        "width": 1,
        "type": "esriSLS",
        "style": "esriSLSSolid"
        }
});
```

and then changed the following

```
    "attributes" : {
        "name" : "XYZ Medical Center",
        "statusID" : "1",
        **"NamedColor":"[0,255,0,204]"**
    },
```

it all worked.  Looking back, I guess JavaScript/jQuery was seeing the [] as an object which makes sense.